# Creating Windows Metro style apps with Java?

Tags: java, windows-8, windows-runtime

I know how to create small desktop applications in Java. I want to know, can I make Windows Metro style apps in Java? Because on the web only C++/C/C#/JavaScript etc. are mentioned. If yes can you please give me some reference for a quick start. If not which one will be easiest language to start?

Comment: It's actually a very interesting question. With WinRT it should be relatively easy to create bindings for Java to the new framework as easily as accessing it from other languages. Just give it a month or two. ;)

Comment: You may have a chance with IKVM :) http://www.ikvm.net/devguide/java2net.html but I don't know how well it works :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can only create metro style apps with C#, VB, JavaScript and C++.  There is currently no support for authoring metro style applications with Java.

Comment: Nor anything else I'd assume.  A fairly closed ecosystem but a broad spectrum of choices within it.

Comment: There are some technical challenges to implementing a JIT'ed language like Java, but it should be relatively straightforward to add windows runtime support to compiled languages.  As long as the code for the language runtime is compiled with the development kit for metro apps, it should be possible.

Comment: But no plans to bring VBScript into the picture I assume, just to mention another Microsoft tool.

Comment: @Bob The ABI is open and documented, so support for third-party languages is entirely possible, if said third-parties are willing to implement it.

Comment: More importantly, the metadata format is a profile of ECMA 335 and we will be documenting the details - but just knowing that it's ECMA 335 is enough to get you 99% of the way there.  We absolutely intended for other languages to support the windows runtime (but as I mentioned, there are challenges for JIT'ed languages)

Comment: Sorry for playing Devil's Advocate here but... COM, vtable dispatch, running under a runtime-provided message loop.  Hmm, too bad there is no unmanaged compiled/p-code VB anymore to retrofit for Metro.

Comment: Martyn Lovell goes into a little detail here about how to enable new languages to run on WinRT: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2012/The-Windows-Runtime

Answer (score 6):

You cannot make metro style apps with Java.

For the other part of your question, regarding starter's guide and which language is easy, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) has a starter's guide which helps building new metro style apps, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385), [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380) should be helpful.

And which language is easiest, well it depends on the developer, someone who has been developing .NET or WPF or Windows Forms applications maybe more comfortable with he familiar environment and may prefer developing using C++ and XAML or VisualBasic, depending on what he has been using before, while someone coming from web development may prefer javascript.

For new developers, i would recommend using C# and XAML, but again it is my choice, and not everyone will agree with it.

[Here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/09/14/how-to-create-windows-8-apps-tutorial/) is another link which points to guides at MSDN, and adds some additional detail.

Answer (score 4):

WinRT is still based on COM, so you should be able to access it from Java using something like [the Java-COM bridge](http://danadler.com/jacob/). Using that would probably be quite hard (you'd have to use strings for method names etc.).

If you wanted to use WinRT comfortably from Java, that would require modifying the Java runtime and possibly also the compiler to make them aware of WinRT types.

Comment: Compiler can probably be left as is if you generate dummy Java classes/interfaces from .winmd files, and hook up JNI to generate object wrappers on the fly. So I think a pure library/JNI solution, portable between JVMs, is possible here, though it wouldn't be as seamless as what .NET does.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you will not be able to use Java and WinRT. The best option for you to try is C#, because this is the language that is closest to java, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can quite easily write a metro style web application by using a CSS library like this one: http://metroui.org.ua/

With this CSS, it is possibly to generate plain old HTML with Java on the server side (e.g. via a servlet) and then reverence the CSS classes.

I did this by using the org.apache.ecs library (it's very old but it works pretty good).

Comment: The question is around creating a thick client application in Java, not a webapp (acknowledged in the question as an option)

Answer (score 0):

C# and Java are similar, but with different Frameworks. Look into developing Metro Style apps in C#. Remember to sign up for a developer's license for Windows Store Apps!

Answer (score 0):

You could write your app in Java and cross compile into JavaScript using GWT.  We do this successfully with a couple of Windows (Phone and Desktop) apps.  Additionally, the code can be shared with your iOS and Android ports.

Answer (score -1):

here what i found in sourceforge.net
http://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/freshness:recently-updated/?q=slibrary
this is the most close ui to metro theme i saw.

Comment: The slibrary project is empty: only 3 screen shots and no code at all. It claims it's based on Swing, not JavaFX.